# Linearity of Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In my probability class, we learned that the expected value of a nonnegative random variable can be defined by

$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty 1-F_{X}(t)\, dt$$

where $F_X$ is the CDF of $X$. I know it is possible to prove that $E[cX] = cE[X]$ for $c>0$ directly from this definition using substitution. Still, I am having difficulty proving that $E[X+Y] = E[X]+E[Y]$ for random variables $X$ and $Y$. Is it possible to do this directly from the definition?

Comment: Think of expectation as integration over  probability measure.

Answer (score 0):

The above formula  is for the special case of non-negative random variable. But linearity holds in all cases.  It is simply a property of definite integrals:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \big(g_1(x) + g_2(x)\big) dx =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g_1(x)  dx  +
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g_2(x) ) dx $$
And $$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty cf(x)dx = c\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx\qquad c\in\mathbf{R}$$
Actually this is not even about probability. In fact this is what is needed to prove linearity of inner product on the vector space consisting of functions satisfying suitable integrabiliy conditions.

Comment: Similarly $$\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R f(x,y)\,(g_1(x)+g_2(y))\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x = \int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R  g_1(x)\, f(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x+\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R  g_2(y)\,f(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x$$